# back button problems with PhoneGap and Jquery-mobile in android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a problem with the android back button, I am following these steps: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html, but when I give the back button, I removed the application, I intend to go to the first div id home.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting:

```
$.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled
```

in order to make JQueryMobile play nice with Phonegap's back button features.

There's more information here:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Answer (score 0):

Apart from jquery-mobile you can use normal "*div*" for rolling your pages up or down. use ".*hide*" in your *.js* file to hide the div except which one you wanted to show, like this

```
$("#1stdiv").hide();
$("#2stdiv").hide();
$("#3stdiv").hide();
$("#4stdiv").show();
$("#5thdiv").hide();
```

to make that in backpage history, implement stack and pop the pages into the stack as soon as you entered in to the page then write *onclick* function on backbutton onclick which should shows top element in stack. like this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 function onDeviceReady(){
     document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
 }
function onBackKeyDown(){
   //hide all div except the div which is in top of stack 
 }
```

But make sure are adding `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` or `<script src="phonegap.js"></script>` on HTML file when you are using in phonegap.