# Phonegap JQuery Mobile Android Back Button issues

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using Phonegap and JQuery mobile to make an app that has a lot of dynamic content. There are a lot of pages that are created dynamically. I need to get the back button working in Android. From this post, [back button problems with PhoneGap and Jquery-mobile in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049374/back-button-problems-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile-in-android), I set $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true and now the button at least acts like I expect it to. It goes back in history, skipping over the dynamically created pages. Before I added that, it was jumping all over the place.

My question is, how do I get those dynamically created pages into the history so that when the Android back button is pushed, it will go back the right way?